# Exibir os campos de uma relação ForeignKey no template

Tags: django, template

Salve Devs... Preciso de um help para exibir os campos de uma tabela que é de relacionamento ForeignKey em um Template.

**models**

```
class IEIS (models.Model):

    nome = models.CharField (max_length=25,null=False, blank=False)
    revisao = models.CharField (max_length=20,null=True, blank=True)
    pit = models.ForeignKey(PIT, related_name='pit', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name= 'PIT - Plano de Inspeção e Teste')

class PIT(models.Model):

    nome = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    fluido = models.ManyToManyField(Fluido, related_name='fluido', blank=True, unique=False)
```

Na Classe IEIS eu tenho o campo PIT como FK. Eu preciso exibir no template de visualização da IEIS, alguns campos da classe PIT.

**views**

````
def view_ieis(request, pk):
    ieis = IEIS.objects.get(pk=pk)
    especs = ieis.especificacao.all()
    fluidos = ieis.fluido.all()
    pits = PIT.objects.get(pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'ieis/view.html', {'ieis': ieis, 'especs': especs, 'fluidos': fluidos, 'pits': pits,})``` 


**ieis.html**
````

PIT

```
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>

        {% for pit in ieis.pits.all %}
            {{ pit }} {{ pit.nome }}
        {% endfor %}

    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

```

Desde já agradeço a toda atenção, sugestão e ajuda dedicada!

Answer (score 0):

Tenta assim:

```py
class PIT(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    fluido = models.ManyToManyField(Fluido, related_name='fluido', blank=True, unique=False)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome
 
class IEIS (models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField (max_length=25,null=False, blank=False)
    revisao = models.CharField (max_length=20,null=True, blank=True)
    pit = models.ForeignKey(PIT, related_name='pit', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name= 'PIT - Plano de Inspeção e Teste')
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome
    
    # Como só quer mostrar no contexto os dados de PIT não precisaria implementar o __str__ no IEIS.
```

E agora no template: deixa só o 'for pit in pits.all'; e obviamente vai repetir o nome dos dados do PIT pois as duas tags devolvem o mesmo valor.

```html
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>

        {% for pit in pits.all %}
            {{ pit }} {{ pit.nome }}
        {% endfor %}

    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: Essa inversão foi na hora montar a pergunta. No código esta correto. Também não consigo entender porque não retorna os campos da tabela PIT. Ele pega como objeto e não os campos.

Comment: Atualizei a resposta, talvez ajude!

Comment: Ajudou sim, obrigado. Peguei uma linha com sua e outras sugestões e consegui sanar.